# Django Rest Framwork - Select only some fields in reverse lookup queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve *only some* of the fields in the "Appointments" associated to a rental property "Unit". From the UnitSerializer, I call a SerializerMethodField() to do a reverse lookup for the "appointment" field. This works out well. However, the queryset returns all the fields (id, time, unit, staff, prospect) in each object, when I only need a few (id, time).

I tried .values() on the queryset like so:

```
queryset = instance.appointment_set.values('id', 'appointment_time')
```

But I get *"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field unit on serializer AppointmentSerializer.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the dict instance.\nOriginal exception text was: unit."*

Note sure if you need all the code, but here's the essential.

**Models**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_time = models.DateTimeField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers**

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['id','appointment_time']


class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    appointment = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'appointment']

    def get_appointment(self, instance):
        cutoff = _datetime.date.today() + timedelta(hours=72)
        queryset = instance.appointment_set.exclude(appointment_time__gt=cutoff)
        return AppointmentSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to handle reverse relationship in serializer:

```
class UnitSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    appointment = AppointmentSerializer(many=True, source='appointment_set')

class Meta:
    model = Unit
    fields = ['id', 'address', 'appointment']
```

Comment: Your solution is much simpler and works perfectly if I don't intend to filter the queryset. However, the reason I was using a SerializerMethodField() in the first place was to eventually filter the queryset like so: queryset = instance.appointment_set.exclude(appointment_time__gt=cutoff). Only from this filtered queryset would I return some of the fields (id, appointment_time). I've updated my question to clarify this.